# Speed up XML ajax request and parse Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, performance, parsing

I have a large (50k+ records) xml file that I am currently reading/parsing with jquery.

It takes quite a while to load and parse using the `$.get` method.

Currently my code looks something like this.

```
$.get('db.xml', {}, function(xml){      
    $("file", xml).each(function(i) {
        var name        = $(this).find("name").text();
        var type        = $(this).find("type").text();
        var path        = $(this).find("path").text();
        var archive     = $(this).find("archive").text();
        var year        = $(this).find("year").text();
        var month       = $(this).find("month").text();
        var date        = $(this).find("date").text();

        var row = $('<tr class="'+type+' '+year+' row">')
            .append($("<td>").html(name))
            .append($("<td>").html(type))
            .append($("<td>").html(path))
            .append($("<td>").html(archive))
            .append($("<td>").html(month))
            .append($("<td>").html(date))
            .append($("<td>").html(year));

        $("tbody").append(row);                         
    }   
});
```

This works but is very slow.

There has to be a more elegant way to do this.

All the other similar questions and their solutions rely on using a perl module or some language that requires a server. However this needs to be able to work from the client side without an internet connection in a browser.

Am I stuck with the load time or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you need all 50K records at once? If not, why is this data stored in XML rather than something more suitable to query against like a database? Also, do you want something elegant or do you want something fast as these might be mutually exclusive.

Comment: This would be much faster if you store it as JSON. The only thing you have to do is JSON.parse() the data returned from the file and you have a fully accessible javascript array of objects that you can simply loop through and access the necessary parts of the object.

Comment: split the xml into alphabetised (for example) chunks and open the file that you need instead of parsing everything at once. e.g. if you need records starting with 'B', open the B.xml file and parse that.

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys. @mikeBrant. I do not need all 50k records at once.. however I cannot use a database as this has to work on the client side/in a browser/without an internet connection.

Comment: @SnowInferno. This seems like the best solution if it will indeed increase speed. Ill give that a shot right now.

Comment: @rudeovski ze bear. Unfortunately even if I split the xml into chunks when I filter data I would have to load each chunk and filter every single one. This seems like it might actually increase the amount of time to query the xml instead of reducing it.

Comment: have you considered using SQLite?

Comment: @mikeBrant I had heard of it but never checked it out. Always assumed it required a  server and was just a stripped version of sql. But if there is a way to implement sql queries/databases without a server I'm all about it

Comment: @dvicemuse Yes most browser have plugins to manage SQLite DB's so if you intent is strictly to be able to distribute a set of files to an end user so that they can view this data, this may be an option for you. I know there is also a jQuery plugin for working with SQLite, but haven't used it so I don't know how full-featured it is.

Comment: @mikeBrant Perfect! found this. [link]http://tejasrpatel.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/create-sqlite-off-line-database-and-insertupdatedeletedrop-operations-in-sqlite-using-jquery-html5-inputs/ .. Seems to be the exact solution I needed to start our inhouse media catalog. Thanks so much. I would still be ripping my hair out right now

Comment: @dvicemuse Glad to have been able to help. One thing I would not however, is that if you don't really need to build the SQLite access app itself (for instance to allow your app to do other things beside SQLite management), I would recommend using one of the available browser plug-ins to manage SQLite. They will be much more full featured than anything you would be likely to develop.